# Purpose of duplicate of xargs in this one-liner

Tags: unix, find, xargs

Could anyone help me to understand the below one-liner?

```
find | xargs grep 'patt' -sl | xargs -L1 sed 's/patt/repl/g'
```

why there are two xargs exist and why it cannot be combined, also man page for **xargs -L** says:

```
-L max-lines: Use at most max-lines nonblank input lines per command line.  Trailing blanks cause an input line to be logically continued on the next input line.  Implies -x
```

Which I am not able to interpret.

Answer (score 1):

The first `xargs` uses the `-l` option to `grep`, which makes it print just the names of the files that have a match for the pattern. So this is taking as input all the files that `find` lists, and filters it down to the files that contain the pattern.

The second `xargs` runs `sed` over each of those files, to replace the pattern with the replacement.

Comment: what is the purpose of **xargs -L1**?

Comment: It runs the command once for each filename, instead of appending all the filenames onto a single command line. I don't know why the programmer did that, there's no reason to start a new `sed` command for each file.